# How to detect native code change in react native app

Tags: react-native, react-native-code-push

I have a React Native app with code push configured and running. We use a variation of semantic versioning.

- Incremental version is incremented automatically, and we use code push for most of these updates.
- Minor version is incremented (mostly) automatically when there are native code changes (necessitating a new app store release).
- Major version is manually specified, and mostly driven by business decisions/major functionality changes.

CodePush builds can target any app store release of the same minor version and lower incremental version (specified in CodePush configuration as `>=2.20.0 <= 2.20.34`, `>=2.23.0 <=2.23.2`, etc).

Our CI/CD pipeline detects native code changes by looking for changes in the `project_root/android` or `project_root/ios` directories, however, we've noticed this misses native code changes (especially since we updated to support autolinking). With iOS, the `Podfile.lock` *usually* updates, and correctly triggers our automatic minor version increment. With Android, updates to our native dependencies are frequently only visible (in git) as changes to the `package.json`, which isn't typically detected.

We could (additionally) trigger our minor version upgrade on every change to our `package.json` 'dependencies' section, but this would result in app store releases that could have just been code pushes (changes to js only libraries).

I'm looking for a better way to detect native code changes, particularly when the change is limited to an Android-only dependency.

Answer (score 0):

For now we are just checking for changes in /iOS and /android folders. It's not as graceful as I would hope but I'm still in search of something better.

Comment: Like I said in the question, that's what we are (were) doing, but it has the problems with native dependencies (also outlined in the question).